# Converting Spell Slots to Sorcery Points

Tags: spell-slots

If a sorcerer decides to convert an unused spell slot into spell points, does the sorcerer gain spell points according to the table on p. 101?  So if I convert a level 1 spell to spell points, do I get 2 spell points as per the Creating Spell Slots table on p. 101, or do I get one spell point because it is a 1st level spell?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to keep in mind that there are thousands of different RPGs in existence; can you clarify for us which game and edition you're asking about?

Comment: @danoh is this for D&D 5e ?

Comment: That edit didn’t solve the problem. What we need to know is **what game are you asking about?** There are thousands of RPGs, so questions need to say clearly what game is being asked about. This sounds like D&D 5th edition — is that the case?

Comment: (Aside, it looks like you lost the login for your account. You’ll have to create a new one and [register it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account), then ask for it to be [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) with this old account.)